# Is 'pair of dress' more correct than 'dress'?

Tags: syntax

Is 'pair of dress' more correct than 'dress'?
Is it syntactically correct if I say 'I donated 20 pairs of dresses'?

Comment: What makes you think a pair of dress is correct? Where did you see it? Why wouldn’t you write a pair of dresses instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generally use pair for things that come in two mirror-symmetrical parts. the two parts may be separate, for example shoes, socks, gloves and slippers or may be joined together, for example glasses, scissors, pants, trousers, tights, pyjamas.

You do not use pair for things that come in ones, like dresses, or things that come in two parts that are not mirror-symmetrical- for example a 2-piece suit.

It is *syntactically* correct to says 20 pairs of dresses (meaning 40 dresses), but there is no particular *logical* reason to do so, and it would sound strange.

Answer (score 1):

A dress is not usually referred to as a 'pair' like a pair of pants might be. Normal usage for your example sentence would be "I donated 20 dresses', or if each 'dress' consists of more than one item of clothing (for example a dress and blouse), you might say 'I donated 20 sets of dresses', or more normally, 'I donated 20 sets of clothing'.